# Prevent Saving PST File Password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to disable "Save this password in your password list", so that the PST password is always requested?

There seems to be a registry setting to "always ask for credentials", but I think those are for the mail server, not the mail file.

This can be for any version of Outlook or Windows. (Maybe, Windows XP or newer, and  Outlook 2003 or newer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, there is no option in outlook to prevent saving password for pst files.

It's possible to password-protect your Outlook data file. However, once Outlook is open, anyone with access to your computer can view the contents of your pst file. For this reason you should secure your computer: when you step away, press Windows key + L to lock it. (And don't share your password!) Each user should have their own Windows user account.

You can check the similar thread discussed in Technet forum:[How to securely protect PST file with a NON-REMOVABLE password?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a6573b38-bfec-4faf-9698-4bb7824971e3/how-to-securely-protect-pst-file-with-a-nonremovable-password?forum=outlook)

You can also see [this article.](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/to-secure-your-personal-folders-pst-file/)